# Publishing 2010 vsto word addin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, vsto

I have made a word 2010 vsto add-in, and it works great within visual studio. However, I'm not sure how to publish it. I tried to right click on the project and publish it, but the add-in doesn't seem to work (Some missing buttons, and no data access.. It doesn't even show me an error when I click the buttons (nothing happens)).I have Visual Studio Installer Tools, but I'm not sure what files to add to the installation file (My project consists of the add-in and some windows forms, and is dependent on an access database file and some word documents that should be present in the final installation directory). If I use Visual Studio Installer Tools, the output is of type .dll and not .vsto, and therefore will not be read by Word in order to be installed. Any ideas?
Thanks
[How it opens within visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSJ2m.png)
[How it opens after installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxzo0.png)

```html
<hostitem:hostItem hostitem:baseType="Microsoft.Office.Tools.AddInBase" hostitem:namespace="MoEAddin" hostitem:className="ThisAddIn" hostitem:identifier="ThisAddIn" hostitem:primaryCookie="AddIn" hostitem:master="true" hostitem:factoryType="Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.ApplicationFactory" hostitem:startupIndex="0" xmlns:hostitem="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/VisualStudio/Tools/Applications/HostItem.xsd">
  <hostitem:hostObject hostitem:name="Application" hostitem:identifier="Application" hostitem:type="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application" hostitem:cookie="Application" hostitem:modifier="Internal" />
  <hostitem:hostControl hostitem:name="CustomTaskPanes" hostitem:identifier="CustomTaskPanes" hostitem:type="Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPaneCollection" hostitem:primaryCookie="CustomTaskPanes" hostitem:modifier="Internal" />
  <hostitem:hostControl hostitem:name="VstoSmartTags" hostitem:identifier="VstoSmartTags" hostitem:type="Microsoft.Office.Tools.SmartTagCollection" hostitem:primaryCookie="VstoSmartTags" hostitem:modifier="Internal" />
</hostitem:hostItem>
```

```
namespace MoEAddin
{
partial class moeRibbon1 : Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    public moeRibbon1()
        : base(Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory())
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.tab1 = this.Factory.CreateRibbonTab();
        this.groupGenerics = this.Factory.CreateRibbonGroup();
        this.groupStudies = this.Factory.CreateRibbonGroup();
        this.groupUserPreferences = this.Factory.CreateRibbonGroup();
        this.buttonGenericLetter = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.buttonGenericReport = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.splitButtonScoping = this.Factory.CreateRibbonSplitButton();
        this.buttonScopingApproval = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.buttonScopingAmendment = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.buttonScopingConditionalApproval = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.splitButtonEIA = this.Factory.CreateRibbonSplitButton();
        this.buttonEIAApproval = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.buttonEIAAmendment = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.buttonEIAConditionalApproval = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.splitButtonIEE = this.Factory.CreateRibbonSplitButton();
        this.buttonIEEApproval = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.buttonIEEAmendment = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.buttonIEEConditionalApproval = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.splitButtonAudit = this.Factory.CreateRibbonSplitButton();
        this.buttonAuditApproval = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.buttonAuditAmendment = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.buttonAuditConditionalApproval = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.buttonUserPreferences = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        this.tab1.SuspendLayout();
        this.groupGenerics.SuspendLayout();
        this.groupStudies.SuspendLayout();
        this.groupUserPreferences.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tab1
        // 
        this.tab1.ControlId.ControlIdType = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlIdType.Office;
        this.tab1.Groups.Add(this.groupGenerics);
        this.tab1.Groups.Add(this.groupStudies);
        this.tab1.Groups.Add(this.groupUserPreferences);
        this.tab1.Label = "MoE";
        this.tab1.Name = "tab1";
        // 
        // groupGenerics
        // 
        this.groupGenerics.Items.Add(this.buttonGenericLetter);
        this.groupGenerics.Items.Add(this.buttonGenericReport);
        this.groupGenerics.Label = "Generics";
        this.groupGenerics.Name = "groupGenerics";
        // 
        // groupStudies
        // 
        this.groupStudies.Items.Add(this.splitButtonScoping);
        this.groupStudies.Items.Add(this.splitButtonEIA);
        this.groupStudies.Items.Add(this.splitButtonIEE);
        this.groupStudies.Items.Add(this.splitButtonAudit);
        this.groupStudies.Label = "Studies";
        this.groupStudies.Name = "groupStudies";
        // 
        // groupUserPreferences
        // 
        this.groupUserPreferences.Items.Add(this.buttonUserPreferences);
        this.groupUserPreferences.Label = "User Preferences";
        this.groupUserPreferences.Name = "groupUserPreferences";
        // 
        // buttonGenericLetter
        // 
        this.buttonGenericLetter.ControlSize = Microsoft.Office.Core.RibbonControlSize.RibbonControlSizeLarge;
        this.buttonGenericLetter.Image = global::MoEAddin.Properties.Resources.LetterIcon;
        this.buttonGenericLetter.Label = "كتاب وزير";
        this.buttonGenericLetter.Name = "buttonGenericLetter";
        this.buttonGenericLetter.ShowImage = true;
        this.buttonGenericLetter.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.buttonGenericLetter_Click);
        // 
        // buttonGenericReport
        // 
        this.buttonGenericReport.ControlSize = Microsoft.Office.Core.RibbonControlSize.RibbonControlSizeLarge;
        this.buttonGenericReport.Image = global::MoEAddin.Properties.Resources.ReportIcon;
        this.buttonGenericReport.Label = "تقرير";
        this.buttonGenericReport.Name = "buttonGenericReport";
        this.buttonGenericReport.ShowImage = true;
        this.buttonGenericReport.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.buttonGenericReport_Click);
        // 
        // splitButtonScoping
        // 
        this.splitButtonScoping.ControlSize = Microsoft.Office.Core.RibbonControlSize.RibbonControlSizeLarge;
        this.splitButtonScoping.Image = global::MoEAddin.Properties.Resources.book_bookmark;
        this.splitButtonScoping.Items.Add(this.buttonScopingApproval);
        this.splitButtonScoping.Items.Add(this.buttonScopingAmendment);
        this.splitButtonScoping.Items.Add(this.buttonScopingConditionalApproval);
        this.splitButtonScoping.Label = "تحديد نطاق تقييم أثر بيئي";
        this.splitButtonScoping.Name = "splitButtonScoping";
        this.splitButtonScoping.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.splitButtonScoping_Click);
        // 
        // buttonScopingApproval
        // 
        this.buttonScopingApproval.Label = "موافقة";
        this.buttonScopingApproval.Name = "buttonScopingApproval";
        this.buttonScopingApproval.ShowImage = true;
        this.buttonScopingApproval.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.buttonScopingApproval_Click);
        // 
        // buttonScopingAmendment
        // 
        this.buttonScopingAmendment.Label = "تعديل التقرير";
        this.buttonScopingAmendment.Name = "buttonScopingAmendment";
        this.buttonScopingAmendment.ShowImage = true;
        this.buttonScopingAmendment.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.buttonScopingAmendment_Click);
        // 
        // buttonScopingConditionalApproval
        // 
        this.buttonScopingConditionalApproval.Label = "موافقة مشروطة";
        this.buttonScopingConditionalApproval.Name = "buttonScopingConditionalApproval";
        this.buttonScopingConditionalApproval.ShowImage = true;
        this.buttonScopingConditionalApproval.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.buttonScopingConditionalApproval_Click);
        // 
        // splitButtonEIA
        // 
        this.splitButtonEIA.ControlSize = Microsoft.Office.Core.RibbonControlSize.RibbonControlSizeLarge;
        this.splitButtonEIA.Image = global::MoEAddin.Properties.Resources.book_bookmark;
        this.splitButtonEIA.Items.Add(this.buttonEIAApproval);
        this.splitButtonEIA.Items.Add(this.buttonEIAAmendment);
        this.splitButtonEIA.Items.Add(this.buttonEIAConditionalApproval);
        this.splitButtonEIA.Label = "تقييم أثر بيئي";
        this.splitButtonEIA.Name = "splitButtonEIA";
        // 
        // buttonEIAApproval
        // 
        this.buttonEIAApproval.Label = "موافقة";
        this.buttonEIAApproval.Name = "buttonEIAApproval";
        this.buttonEIAApproval.ShowImage = true;
        this.buttonEIAApproval.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.buttonEIAApproval_Click);
        // 
        // buttonEIAAmendment
        // 
        this.buttonEIAAmendment.Label = "تعديل التقرير";
        this.buttonEIAAmendment.Name = "buttonEIAAmendment";
        this.buttonEIAAmendment.ShowImage = true;
        this.buttonEIAAmendment.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.buttonEIAAmendment_Click);
        // 
        // buttonEIAConditionalApproval
        // 
        this.buttonEIAConditionalApproval.Label = "موافقة مشروطة";
        this.buttonEIAConditionalApproval.Name = "buttonEIAConditionalApproval";
        this.buttonEIAConditionalApproval.ShowImage = true;
        this.buttonEIAConditionalApproval.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.buttonEIAConditionalApproval_Click);
        // 
        // splitButtonIEE
        // 
        this.splitButtonIEE.ControlSize = Microsoft.Office.Core.RibbonControlSize.RibbonControlSizeLarge;
        this.splitButtonIEE.Image = global::MoEAddin.Properties.Resources.book_bookmark;
        this.splitButtonIEE.Items.Add(this.buttonIEEApproval);
        this.splitButtonIEE.Items.Add(this.buttonIEEAmendment);
        this.splitButtonIEE.Items.Add(this.buttonIEEConditionalApproval);
        this.splitButtonIEE.Label = "تقييم بيئي مبدئي";
        this.splitButtonIEE.Name = "splitButtonIEE";
        this.splitButtonIEE.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.splitButtonIEE_Click);
        // 
        // buttonIEEApproval
        // 
        this.buttonIEEApproval.Label = "موافقة";
        this.buttonIEEApproval.Name = "buttonIEEApproval";
        this.buttonIEEApproval.ShowImage = true;
        this.buttonIEEApproval.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.buttonIEEApproval_Click);
        // 
        // buttonIEEAmendment
        // 
        this.buttonIEEAmendment.Label = "تعديل التقرير";
        this.buttonIEEAmendment.Name = "buttonIEEAmendment";
        this.buttonIEEAmendment.ShowImage = true;
        this.buttonIEEAmendment.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.buttonIEEAmendment_Click);
        // 
        // buttonIEEConditionalApproval
        // 
        this.buttonIEEConditionalApproval.Label = "طلب تقييم أثر بيئي";
        this.buttonIEEConditionalApproval.Name = "buttonIEEConditionalApproval";
        this.buttonIEEConditionalApproval.ShowImage = true;
        this.buttonIEEConditionalApproval.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.buttonIEEConditionalApproval_Click);
        // 
        // splitButtonAudit
        // 
        this.splitButtonAudit.ControlSize = Microsoft.Office.Core.RibbonControlSize.RibbonControlSizeLarge;
        this.splitButtonAudit.Image = global::MoEAddin.Properties.Resources.book_bookmark;
        this.splitButtonAudit.Items.Add(this.buttonAuditApproval);
        this.splitButtonAudit.Items.Add(this.buttonAuditAmendment);
        this.splitButtonAudit.Items.Add(this.buttonAuditConditionalApproval);
        this.splitButtonAudit.Label = "تدقيق بيئي";
        this.splitButtonAudit.Name = "splitButtonAudit";
        // 
        // buttonAuditApproval
        // 
        this.buttonAuditApproval.Label = "موافقة";
        this.buttonAuditApproval.Name = "buttonAuditApproval";
        this.buttonAuditApproval.ShowImage = true;
        this.buttonAuditApproval.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.buttonAuditApproval_Click);
        // 
        // buttonAuditAmendment
        // 
        this.buttonAuditAmendment.Label = "تعديل التقرير";
        this.buttonAuditAmendment.Name = "buttonAuditAmendment";
        this.buttonAuditAmendment.ShowImage = true;
        this.buttonAuditAmendment.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.buttonAuditAmendment_Click);
        // 
        // buttonAuditConditionalApproval
        // 
        this.buttonAuditConditionalApproval.Label = "موافقة مشروطة";
        this.buttonAuditConditionalApproval.Name = "buttonAuditConditionalApproval";
        this.buttonAuditConditionalApproval.ShowImage = true;
        this.buttonAuditConditionalApproval.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.buttonAuditConditionalApproval_Click);
        // 
        // buttonUserPreferences
        // 
        this.buttonUserPreferences.ControlSize = Microsoft.Office.Core.RibbonControlSize.RibbonControlSizeLarge;
        this.buttonUserPreferences.Image = global::MoEAddin.Properties.Resources.Bolt_Preferences;
        this.buttonUserPreferences.Label = "خصائص عامّة";
        this.buttonUserPreferences.Name = "buttonUserPreferences";
        this.buttonUserPreferences.ShowImage = true;
        this.buttonUserPreferences.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.buttonUserPreferences_Click);
        // 
        // moeRibbon1
        // 
        this.Name = "moeRibbon1";
        this.RibbonType = "Microsoft.Word.Document";
        this.Tabs.Add(this.tab1);
        this.Load += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonUIEventHandler(this.moeRibbon1_Load);
        this.tab1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tab1.PerformLayout();
        this.groupGenerics.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupGenerics.PerformLayout();
        this.groupStudies.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupStudies.PerformLayout();
        this.groupUserPreferences.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupUserPreferences.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonTab tab1;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonGroup groupGenerics;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonGroup groupStudies;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton buttonGenericLetter;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton buttonGenericReport;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonSplitButton splitButtonScoping;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonSplitButton splitButtonEIA;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonSplitButton splitButtonIEE;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonSplitButton splitButtonAudit;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton buttonScopingApproval;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton buttonScopingAmendment;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton buttonEIAApproval;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton buttonEIAAmendment;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton buttonIEEApproval;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton buttonIEEAmendment;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton buttonAuditApproval;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton buttonAuditAmendment;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton buttonScopingConditionalApproval;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton buttonEIAConditionalApproval;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton buttonIEEConditionalApproval;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton buttonAuditConditionalApproval;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonGroup groupUserPreferences;
    internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton buttonUserPreferences;
}

partial class ThisRibbonCollection
{
    internal moeRibbon1 moeRibbon1
    {
        get { return this.GetRibbon<moeRibbon1>(); }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The *Publish* command creates a *Click-Once* installer for you. Did you execute that installer?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I did, but the end result is different than the one within visual studio (the add in is missing some buttons and is devoid of any meaningful commands, it only opens new forms, but does not access the db or access Word.Interop methods...etc
 
I have added some images in the original question. Appreciate your help